# Did Facebook bot stop adhering to the ?_escaped_fragment= AJAX crawling thing?

Tags: ajax, facebook, bots, shebang

For a long time it used to be possible to serve a page for bots when the URL contained `#!somethingLikeThis` and behind the scenes that would get requested by the bot as `?_escaped_fragment=somethingLikeThis` but this seem to no longer work. Is there an official note about why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find an official note from Facebook, but [here](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2017/12/rendering-ajax-crawling-pages.html) is an official note from Google on the same subject. They are stopping using deprecated [AJAX crawling scheme](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more) because their crawler `Googlebot` is able now to render `JavaScript` linked pages without this workaround.

I guess that Facebook accomplished the same result with their crawler. 
If it is so, then you don't need anymore to use `#!` url syntax and provide rendered version of your web pages for crawlers.

Answer (score 1):

No information regarding this is announced or given in facebook and therehelp center.